# A list iterator reference - Program output

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, iterator

Given the following algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main ()
{
  std::list<int> mylist = {5,10,15,20};

  std::cout << "mylist contains:"<<"\n";

  //for (auto it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it)
  auto it = mylist.begin();
  while ( it != mylist.end())
  {
      std::cout << *it;
      std::cout << "    "<< &it<<std::endl;
      it++;
  }

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
mylist contains:
 5     0x7dc9445e5b50
 10    0x7dc9445e5b50
 15    0x7dc9445e5b50
 20    0x7dc9445e5b50
```

**Since we are moving our iterator, why the address doesn't change?**

I was excepting a 4 bytes offset of the reference.

Comment: `&it` is the address of the iterator, not the address of the object it refers to.

Comment: You might want to learn about [range `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: The address of a variable never changes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
  std::cout << "    "<< &*it<<std::endl;
```

Read this for a description of legacy bidirectional iterators.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator

It's not incredibly obvious from this documentation but for this iterator and for iterators in general throughout STL the operator *() will return either:

```
  T & operator *();
```

or

```
  const T & operator *() const; // for const iterators (list iterator in this case).
```

I hope this is a bit more explanatory than my previous rather terse answer.

Comment: Please don't work around the rules of the site. See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: ...and why the code in the question didn't.

Comment: I figured, like you Francois, I would provide the answer and let the asker check on cppreference for the result of the operator *(), etc.

Comment: Honestly, I don't really want to answer questions, but I find *many* instances where I would like to comment on something for further explanations, however, in the 3-4 months I have been on here I somehow cannot get above 50 points so I am unable to comment ever. I have been coding C++ professionally for 33 years so this is rather frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for finally getting me above the threshold so that I can ask questions about other people's solutions to things. I appreciate it. I was a long time coming. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pretty simple: `it` is a variable. Right now, you're printing out the *address* of that variable. You assign different *values* to that variable, but the variable is stored at the same location in memory for the entirety of its existence, so when you print out its address, you see the same value every time.

What you want to do is print out the value stored in that variable--the address of the object to which the iterator refers. In the case of an iterator, it can be somewhat tricky to do that, because an iterator is an abstraction--by design, you don't really know what it contains.

We can, however, take a fairly solid *guess* about how an iterator for an `std::list` is probably implemented. In particular, it's probably something like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
class iterator {
    T *data;
public:
    T &operator*() { return *data; }

    // ... and many more functions we don't care about for now
};
```

The important point here is that although `it` may store different data to produce its result, `operator*` needs to return a reference to the object to which the iterator refers. So, to get the address that's (at least effectively) stored *in* the iterator, we can use `operator*` to get a reference to the object, then `&` to take the address of that object.

The downside: while this tells you the addresses of the objects the iterator refers to at different times, it doesn't necessarily tell you what the iterator itself really contains. As long as the iterator produces the correct results from the specified operations, the iterator is free to produce them in essentially any way it sees fit (but that said, with an iterator for an `std::list`, yes, it's probably going to use a pointer).